# Faster Algorithm than Dijikstra for finding shortest path to all nodes starting from one node

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I'm searching for an algorithm that is similar to dijikstra, but faster. I have to solve the same problem - to find the shortest path to all nodes, starting from a given node. But my teacher tod me, I should find a faster algorithm, as dijikstra could be slow. Also i wanted to ask, if i could use Floyd Marshall's algorithm for that task

Comment: Is there something specific in the problem that may lay an additional restriction? In that case, there may be an specific variation of dijikstra algorithm which may work faster locally.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan All we know about the graph is that it is weighted and directed, with no cycles, if that helps you

Comment: Additioal _sorting_ which helps pruning too costly branches, might help to some degree. Wether Floyd Marshall's algorithm is interesting, yes. But whether it helps, means first understanding the algorithm and what it exactly solves. Better than hopping from algorithm to algorithm, I would look for angles to improve upon Dijkstra. You might need to build in tracing.

Comment: Do you have negative arc weights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/) is a solution to this problem if all arcs are non-negative, otherwise Bellmann-Ford.
To get all shortest paths:

1. Do a topological sort.
2. Breadth-first search from the root and update distances.
   Done.

Just from **one node v**, start from *v*, instead of your root. In the worst case your node *v* is the root anyways. So time-complexity remains = *O(|V|+|E|)*.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra is the optimal algorithm to find the shortest path from a node to the rest if it´s not a specific graph always as arc weigth is positive otherwise you need use Bellmann-Ford algorithm. In your case it´s a DAG, this is a special graph, how it has not cycles, you never come back to a previous state, so, there is a unique path from any node to another(or none). Thus, algorithms as [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) are suitable even if the arcs are negative.

Comment: @Luka does your algorithm have a name?

Comment: @LachezarValev the DFS is a topological sort and BFS is the acronym of Breadth-first search. In my answer I just wanted to point out that you don't need Bellman-Ford for a DAG even if the edges are negative weighted.

Comment: idk if you've read my question, but i needed a faster algorithm than dijikstra's, so the idea with the topological sort is the one i needed. Still appreciate your answer tho :)

Comment: @LachezarValev I read your question and my answer has to do with it. As I said, there is no algorithm more optimal than Disjktra to find shortest path in a general graph, but your case is not general so you can use the solutions that I suggested that are faster than use Disjktra and is same than previous answer, but I wanted you to know that you could use them even if the arcs were negative, opposite to what the previous answer says.

Comment: @Carlos_Julio ok got it :)